# asp.net core - Simplest Authentication - just two lines?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I'm new to asp.net core and was thinking about the simplest way I could set up authentication.  When a user signs in, I could set a session variable and I'll clear the session variable when they log out.  Then in my _layout.cshtml file I simply add something like:

```
if (Context.Request.Path.ToString().ToLower().Contains("/admin") && Context.Session.GetString("Admin") == null)
{
    Context.Response.Redirect("/Home/SignIn");
}
```

Are there any problems with this or any reasons it's a bad idea for simple/basic authentication?

Comment: You should do that in an action filter or middleware.  For example, that won't stop database writes.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about that.  I was able to set up an ActionFilter easily so will put the code there.